# The app works on emulator but not on actual device

Tags: android

I just wanted help in my android app actually scene is like ,I have made an android app that stores and fetch data from mysql database,so the twist is whenever I run app on android emulator it runs fine but as soon as I try to run it on actual device there seem to be nothing is happening however the login and register buttons seem to be doing nothing they don't call the api,I am using wamp as local server and my device and laptop is on same wifi network router so I am not getting it,btw the logcat shows no error at all and it also runs perfectly on emulator
my register activity to add user into database

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = Register.class.getSimpleName();
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private EditText signupInputName, signupInputEmail, signupInputPassword;
public Button btnSignUp;
public Button btnLinkLogin;
private SQLiteHandler db;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    SessionManager  session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this,
                Matchboard.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    signupInputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    signupInputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);


    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = signupInputName.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = signupInputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = signupInputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                registerUser(name, email, password);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    btnLinkLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}




private void registerUser(final String name,  final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    progressDialog.setMessage("Adding you ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {

                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");
                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi "+name+",You are successfully Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Register.this,
                            Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Added the code, is it giving you any reference to my problem or I need to post more code @AbdulWaheed

Comment: because your laptop/computer is connected with lan that's y it is working on emulator because emulator is also accessing lan. You need to use public ip address then it will work over wifi as well. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: oh you mean to say I need to use my public IP instead of using local IP of my machine.i will try and let you know very soon...thanks

Comment: yes you got me right... and let me know if you found any problem

Comment: I just wanted to ask that whether I need to change the lines of URL_LOGIN and URL_REGISTER from whatever 192.168 is there to my public IP(internet ip) but when try to get the JSON response by changing the ip, I don't get anything it is not able to access to the storage of my files in my computer , so do you think my phone will be able to get that , hope I am making sense.

Comment: it's not working, the situation remains same, I checked by changing the IP address to my public IP but nothing changes from previous state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when you are on your local machine the call to made to the localhost but when the app is on your actual device there might be some IP issue.You might be accessing it wrongly.
The thing is that your actual device and the system should be on the same network.
Check your IP using ipconfig command and then retry on same network.

Comment: bro,i checked it more than once there aren't any issue and i have done this thing in past so i do know the credentials but however nothing seem to work

Comment: Do some sort of debugging and make sure you are able to access the server by the way which networking library you are using??

Comment: my device and laptop are on the same router but I don't know whats going on.my target sdk is 23 and minimum sdk is 17

Comment: volley @Abhishek Dubey

Comment: database is mysql and php is there at back end

Comment: is there any problem in  the above-written code or should I also provide manifest and Gradle file also or something with my phone and I have tried to run it on a Samsung as well as Eureka phone but again the user interface looks ok but HTTP connection is not working, it is not accessing the database

Comment: Today I disconnected with my previous network and connected both computer and phone on another router and did some debugging and apparently, it worked after few tries so, i would like to respect your suggestion and mark it as accepted answer ,thanks for your time...

Comment: Keep Coding buddy